# Обособление оборота с предлогом «вместо» – еще одно «неправильное» правило?

Tags: пунктуация, предлоги, авторская-пунктуация

Цитирую Розенталя:

3. Оборот с предлогом "вместо" обособляется в двух случаях:

1. как дополнение, **зависящее от глагола-сказуемого**: Вместо весёлой петербургской жизни, ожидала меня скука в стороне глухой и отдалённой (П.) — оборот связан со сказуемым (‘и то и другое могло ожидать меня’); **обособление факультативно**;
2. как **особая конструкция, не управляемая глаголом-сказуемым**: Вместо ответа, Кириле Петровичу подали письмо (П.) — оборот синтаксически не связан со сказуемым, поскольку не образуется словосочетание подать ответ;  **обособление обязательно.**
   Вместо ответа на какой-то запрос, Зурин захрипел и присвистнул (П.) — то же самое: слово "ответ" **лексически не сочетается** со словами "захрипел к присвистнул"; **обособление обязательно.**
   https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=116#pp116

Но писатели правила не читают и оборот не обособляют или обособляют по своему усмотрению, например:

**Вместо ответа** рыжий снял котелок и взял его на отлёт. [М. А. Булгаков. (1929-1940)]

**Вместо ответа** Ванька стрелой бросился к выходу и исчез в дверях, как испуганная летучая мышь. [Д. Н. Мамин-Сибиряк. (1891)]

Дум-Дум **вместо ответа** постучал ладонью по голове. [Михаил Тырин. (2014)]

**Вместо ответа** она протянула мне клочок бумаги, на котором писала. [Вера Белоусова. (2000)]

Почему в приведенных примерах оборот не обособлен? Может быть, правило некорректно и нуждается в редактировании? Или дело не в этом конкретном правиле, а в том, что однозначные регламентации (в любой теме) в принципе не оправдывают себя?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ-КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Спасибо за ответы.

1. **Правила Лопатина**

Если следовать Лопатину, то ***ответ*** – это существительное, обозначающее действие. Тогда оборот должен обособляться. В Нацкорпусе примерно 1200 самых **разных** примеров с «вместо ответа». [https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=вместо+ответа](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0)

При просмотре их видно, что обособляются считанные единицы. Так, из первых 40 примеров только одно обособление: **Вместо ответа**, подал ей сетку с банкой: [В. М. Шапко. 2014]

2. **Правила Розенталя**

Формальное управление, которого вроде бы  желательно избежать (подал письмо, а не ответ), встречается  реже, но всё-таки встречается (но обособления все равно нет): Войпель подошел к хозяину и вместо ответа положил на снег крохотный кусочек дерева ― клык его вырвал щепку. [Александр Григоренко. 2011]

Розенталь  в правилах приводит и другие примеры для обязательного обособления:  Вместо ответа на какой-то запрос, Зурин **захрипел и присвистнул** (П.) — то же самое: **слово ответ лексически не сочетается со словами захрипел к присвистнул**; **обособление обязательно**.

А вот таких примеров очень много: Вместо ответа мне послышались тихие, словно детские, всхлипывания  [М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. (1858)] Вместо ответа она довольно громко засвистела носом. [Василий Аксенов. (2007)] И т.д.

3. Вот и создается впечатление, что правила вообще не используется для решения этого вопроса.

Comment: я сейчас заметил, что в первом примере второго пункта Р. говорит о ***синтаксической*** связи, а во втором - о ***лексической***. Строго говоря, это разные вещи, может путать. Но вопрос-то у меня другой. Вы понимаете то, что написал Alex_andr?!  Я просто не могу понять его логику.

Comment: *Если следовать Лопатину, то ответ – это существительное, обозначающее действие.* - Тоже не понимаю. По мне так - не обязательно. И вообще, не это у Лопатина главное.

Comment: *Вместо ответа мне послышались тихие, словно детские, всхлипывания* (С-Щ). - Вот тут уж точно не действие. "послышался не ответ, а всхлипывания". А если действие, то совсем в другом понимании, не в том, которое вы привносите своей трактовкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы не сказал, что правило некорректно, нуждается скорее не в уточнении, а в пояснении: когда и как его надо применять.
У Лопатина это правило сформулировано более подробно.

> Примечание 2. Оборот с предлогом вместо, имеющий значение замещения,
> может включать существительные, обозначающие действия или предметы. В
> первом случае оборот всегда выделяется запятыми, во втором —
> обособление необязательно. Ср. примеры: Вместо ответа, он начал
> толкать меня головой в грудь (М. Г.). — Вместо шляпы он купил себе
> старую-фуражку (М. Г.) (значения: не ответил, а начал толкать; купил
> фуражку, а не шляпу);

https://orfhographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=214

Может, у Розенталя тоже есть оговорки на этот счет, не буду искать.
Но если прямо следовать Лопатину,  ваших примерах обособление не обязательно. За исключением, разве что, примера из Тырина, где оборот вклинивается между подлежащим и сказуемым и его хочется обособить просто ради наглядности.

Впрочем, сам Лопатин не дает четкого инструмента разделения двух случаев, упомянутых в цитируемом выше фрагменте: существительное-предмет и существительное-действие. Как это все совместить в объективно верный ответ на ваши запросы я, откровенно говоря, не знаю. На практике, не будь эти тексты освящены именем автора и временем, я запятые бы поставил от греха подальше.

(+)====
По итогам общения с @Aleх_andr.
Как я понимаю Розенталя.

~1. Второй пункт из процитированного в вопросе фрагмента у Р.:

> Оборот с предлогом "вместо" обособляется в двух случаях:
> ...
> как особая конструкция, не управляемая глаголом-сказуемым:

НЕ означает требования не обособлять оборот, если такая такое управление имеется. Он лишь ограничивает рамки императивного требования на обособление. В остальных случаях обособление или его отсутствие определяются другими мотивами. В частности - теми, которые изложены в моей цитате из Лопатина.

~2 Само требование на "отсутствие управления" четко не сформулировано, что позволяет в отдельных случаях допускать авторскую трактовку, но не до такой же степени чтобы видеть возсможность "прямого управления в примерах их Булгакова или Щедрина. Я так понимаю Розенталя, что наличие управление у него предопределяется возможностью трактовки сочетания существительного+глагол как прямого дополнения первого при втором, в примере из Пушкина: "ожидала [как я думал] веселая жизнь" - в этом (и только в этом!) случае обособление по Розенталю ФАКУЛЬТАТИВНО. Хотя у Пушкина оно присутствует.

В примерах из Булгакова и Мамина-Сибиряка ничего похоже даже отдаленно не просматривается. Ни "взять/снять ответ" (МАБ), ни тем более "исчезнуть ответу" (бросился - вообще не может иметь прямого дополнения) в принципе не возможно по смыслу.

~3. Отсутствие обособления в четырех примерах может объясняться чем угодно, но только не правилами из Розенталя в цитируемом здесь объеме. Возможно, у Р. где-то есть оговорки на этот счет, у Лопатина они точно есть.

Answer (score 1):

Розенталь прав в обязательности запятой для приведённого им примера (без неё возможна трактовка, что Троекуров ждал "подачи ответа"). В этом смысле четвертый пример из вопроса - *ошибка* корректоров. В остальных же не возникает необходимости *обособить конструкцию* "**вместо ответа**" от формального *управления глаголом*: вместо одного действия (ответа) персонаж совершает другое, и явно над *другими* сущностями (в случае Булгакова можно было бы разве что злонамеренно рассмотреть "снятие ответа" с головы). Да, у Розенталя не просматривается строгого правила для распознания таких случаев, но пример ясен по смыслу.

Comment: *не возникает необходимости обособить конструкцию "вместо ответа" от формального управления глаголом* - Помилуйте, но Розенталь, если ставить вопрос ребром, вообще не говорит ни о каком "управлении глаголом" как причине отказа от обособления.  Возможно, правда, мы все трое по-разному понимаем мотивирующую часть правила у Р.

Comment: "не управляемая глаголом-сказуемым" - из п.2

Comment: Так это это императивное требование для ОБОСОБЛЕНИЯ. А не для отказа от него.

Comment: Да, постановка запятой исключает управление "ответа" "подачей" ("подали письмо, а не ответ").

Comment: но вы-то в своем используете это утверждение как мотивацию для обратного трtбования - НЕ ОБОСОБЛЯТЬ. Если это так, то я не понимаю этой логики. От слова "совсем".

Comment: Нет, я разделяю случаи, когда необходимо обособить (снять "управление") и когда этого не требуется (ложного управления изначально нет).

Comment: Вы противоречите тому, что говорите в ответе: *не возникает необходимости обособить конструкцию "вместо ответа" от формального управления глаголом*. - Во всяком случае, я не понимаю логики. Подробно о том, как я понимаю - Р. в тексте моего ответа. Спасибо.

Comment: Это касается первых трех примеров (из 4-х) из вопроса.

Comment: Что "это"?  Впрочем, я уже понял бесперспективность попыток понять вашу логику. Свою я изложил.

Comment: "Это" - отсутствие необходимости в запятой.

Comment: Но я же сказал, что не вижу логики в таком понимании. Всё, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

1. Розенталь и Лопатин по-разному излагают тему, но сходятся в том, что в некоторых случаях обособление оборотов с предлогом «вместо» **обязательно**. Вероятно, по их мнению, необособленный  оборот **не вписывается в предложение**. Розенталь связывает это с **лексической  и грамматической несочетаемостью**.
2. Если взять конкретный оборот «вместо ответа», то он вряд ли обладает какой-либо сочетаемостью вообще, а по Лопатину «ответ» – это отглагольное существительное, обозначающее действие «ответить».  То есть решение у наших классиков будет одинаковое: оборот **должен всегда обособляться.** Но пользователи поступают с этим оборотом с точностью наоборот, то есть практически никогда его не обособляют.
3. Как это можно объяснить? Я полагаю, что грамматическая и лексическая сочетаемость этому обороту не так уж нужна, потому что он может быть **ДЕТЕРМИНАНТОМ**, то есть свободным членом предложения, без грамматической связи с другими членами. В этой функции он практически соответствует обособленному обороту, поэтому его и не обособляют.
4. Но определенные ограничения всё-таки есть, когда **несочетаемость слишком очевидна**, то есть бросается в глаза и напрягает слух (и это общее правило для языка). В примере  «*Вместо ответа ему подали письмо*» обособление не выглядит обязательным (как я думаю, у Пушкина факультативное обособление и желание логически подчеркнуть оборот). Но вот в предложении «*Вместо ответа, подал ей сетку с банкой*» при пропущенном подлежащем и прямом контакте с глаголом оборот желательно обособить. Это как раз и есть **формальная несочетаемость и видимость нежелательного управления**, которую следует избегать и о которой говорил Alex_ander.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (ответ на комментарий)

Ну что ж, можно считать, что слово «ответ» может обозначать  **и действие, и предмет.**  В примере у Лопатина это **действие** (не ответил, а толкнул),  в других случаях это **предмет**, который воспринимается на слух (как смех, плач и другие звуки).

И тогда наши составители правил предоставляют нам возможность развить свое логическое мышление. Например, такое задание. В следующих предложениях выберите правильный вариант и объясните свое решение сначала по Розенталю, а потом по Лопатину; сравните ответы.

**По Розенталю:** (1)  Вместо ответа,  он только присвистнул (несочетаемость, нельзя присвистнуть ответ).  (2)  Вместо ответа я услышал его  смех (услышать можно и ответ, и смех).  (3)  Вместо ответа, ему подали записку (несочетаемость, нельзя подать ответ).

**По Лопатину:** (1)  Вместо ответа,  он только присвистнул (действие).  (2)  Вместо ответа я услышал  его смех (предмет).  (3)  Вместо ответа ему подали записку (предмет).

Можно добавить, что в реальных текстах эти обороты вряд ли будут обособляться. Но тогда что можно сказать **по поводу актуальности  правил?** Скорее всего, здесь действуют какие-то другие законы письма.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожплуйста мой пример из С-Щ. *Вместо ответа мне послышались тихие, словно детские, всхлипывания (С-Щ).* Он одновременно служит и иллюстрацией разности подходов Р. и Л.  и опровергает ваш тезис о несочетаемости "[вместо] ответа" с глаголом. Лопатин в этом случае должен трактовать "ответ" как предмет, а не как действие. Просто предмет - не самое удачное слово, правильнее бы сказать "объект".